# JS скрипт для смены даты

Tags: javascript, поиск-библиотек

Нужен скрипт для смены даты в определенное время.
К примеру, сегодня до 12 часов дня я вижу дату завтрашнего дня, а после 12 часов дня, вижу дату послезавтра.
Видел как просто отобразить дату сегодняшнего дня или завтрашнего, а вот замену в определенное время не нашел...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let date = new Date();
let min = date.getMinutes();
let hh = date.getHours();
let dd = date.getDate();
let mm = date.getMonth() + 1; //так как месяца начинаются с 0
let yy = date.getFullYear();

(hh <= 12) ? dd += 1 : dd += 2;

if (min < 10) min = "0" + min;
if (hh < 10) hh = "0" + hh;
if (dd < 10) dd = "0" + dd;
if (mm < 10) mm = "0" + mm;

let neededDate = `${dd}.${mm}.${yy} ${hh}:${min}`;

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = `<p> ${neededDate} </p>`;
document.body.append(div);
```

Comment: но учти, что если это последние 2 дня месяца, то например 29 февраля покажет 31 февраля. Чтобы этого избежать тебе придется написать много if на каждый месяц... да..

Comment: Вопрос, тут вывод в консоль идет, как его в div выводить?

Comment: @DariusKlauey исправил ответ под вывод в бади

Comment: спасибо огромное